# problem with putting query into $this -> in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

the engine in using zend, here is my get query

```
<input type="text" name="q" value="<?php echo $this->query->getQuery(); ?>">
```

and here is my title tag

```
$this->headTitle('Homepage');
```

I would like to put the query keyword replacing Homepage, I have tried parsing many different codes but out of luck, anyone can help?

Comment: You should be using business logic, eg your query, inside your view. The Controller should provide the view with all the data it needs to be displayed. The view should not be handling the query directly. Anyway, what is it your asking? You want the result of your query to be your title tag?

Comment: @jakenoble, Correction: you *shouldn't* be putting business logic inside your view.

Comment: I hope `getQuery` doesn't return SQL.

Comment: @strager I don't think he thinks about a query as in a SQL query, but the query string from the request: `?foo=bar`

Comment: @strager  Thanks - typo, too late to edit now :-(

Comment: no, without get sql data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->headTitle($this->query->getQuery());
```

Or perhaps something a little more user friendly:

```
$this->headTitle('Search results for: &quot;'.$this->query->getQuery().'&quot;');
```

This code can go in your controller, view or plugins - whichever you feel is the most logical. If it's not in the view you'll need to change $this to whatever it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query from the request with the `getQuery()` method.